# Unable to make HTTP/2 connections using Netty while Bouncy castle in classpath

Tags: java, ssl, netty, bouncycastle

When using Netty with OpenSSL provider as SSL provider there seems to be a clash with Bouncy castle jars. I'm trying to connect using a P12 certificate to a HTTP/2 server. The error I get after enabling the java debug log is:

```
ssl: Ignoring alias key: signature does not conform to negotiated signature algorithms
```

The point at which it fails is when adding SslContext to the ChannelPipeline:

```
pipeline.addLast(sslContext.newHandler(channel.alloc()));
```

I'm using the IBM Java on a Websphere Liberty server.

One workaround I'm trying, is to keep the bouncy castle in a separate class loader. But is there a way to generate the Netty's "io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext" using Bouncy castle for HTTP/2 connections with OpenSSL provider?